# Resetting previous selection in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have two [custom select input](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components) fields in a form: **Country** and **City**. City is depended on the Country, as you may have already guessed. So when a user selects a country:

- an ajax call is performed
- the cities of that selected country are fetched
- fetched cities are displayed in the second selectbox

Scenario: From the country selectbox, I selected United States. From the city selectbox I selected Texas (which has the value: 6). Now if I go back to the first select box and change the country to United Kingdom, it will automatically select the 6th city of UK based on the previous selection.

Here is what I am doing:

```
<custom-select type="select" name="country_id" @change="selectCountry">
   <option disabled selected>Choose a Country</option>
   <option v-for="country in countries" :value="country.id">@{{ country.name }}</option>
</custom-select>

<custom-select type="select" name="city_id" @change="selectCity">
   <option disabled selected>Choose a City</option>
   <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}</option>
</custom-select>
```

How do I reset the city selection everytime I select a country?

Comment: just reset the city value in your `selectCountry` function...

Comment: How can I reset it?

Comment: that depends entirely on your `selectCountry` and what variable you're using for `\custom-select`

Comment: In my selectCountry() I am performing an axios call to fetch the cities. In custom select component, I have no extra variables.

Comment: then include all relevant data.

Comment: If I had known what those relevant data might be, I would not have posted the question.

Comment: well I don't know what your selectCountry is doing for one.

Comment: I just told you in my 4th comment.

Comment: Then I will tell you exactly what to do based on the information. Change what `selectCountry` is doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that Vue tries to reuse existing HTML in order to speed up rendering. In your case it chooses not to rerender HTML for select boxes, and it just changes text content of options. Simple way to say force rerendering is to use different key prop for city select depending on selected country:

```
<custom-select type="select" :key="selectedCountryId" name="city_id" @change="selectCity">
   <option disabled selected>Choose a City</option>
   <option v-for="city in cities" :value="city.id">@{{ city.name }}</option>
</custom-select>
```

Note, I added `:key="selectedCountryId"` to the city select. You will need to create this `selectedCountryId` property in `selectCountry` method, for example:

```
selectCountry (e) {
  this.selectedCountryId = e.target.selectedIndex
  axios.get(...)
}
```

Comment: It's not a HTML issue. It's because it's regarding the city value as being index `5`. Which means regardless of what country it is, it will always be selecting the 6th city. The city display isn't the issue.

Comment: @A.Lau wait a little until OP checks it ;) Or if you want you can check it yourself in this simple demo i set up: https://codesandbox.io/s/2zkpo8532n

Comment: @dfsq, It works! I didn't know that vue doesn't rerender. Thanks for the info. Also, since my options values are numeric, and I am receiving `value` as the argument in selectCountry(value), can I use this instead: `this.selectedCountryId = value;` ? Or is it a bad practice?

Comment: @Eisenheim It's not a bad practice, this `:key` just needs to be different for different countries, doesn't matter what it is, as long as it changes with country change.

Answer (score 1):

I am going to show how to do that using a simple example:

You can also, [see it in action by clicking here](https://jsfiddle.net/Roland1993/5zpxomw3/)

```
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selectedState" @change="stateChanged">
    <option :value="null">Select State</option>
    <option
      v-for="state in states"
      :key="state.id"
     :value="state.id"
     >
       {{state.text}}
     </option>
  </select>

  <select v-model="selectedCity">
    <option :value="null">Select City</option>
    <option
      v-for="city in citiesDependOnSelectedState"
      :key="city.id"
      :value="city.id"
     >
       {{city.text}}
     </option>
  </select>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    states: [
      { text: "Albania", id: 1 },
      { text: "Greece", id: 2 },
      { text: "Italy", id: 3 },
      { text: "Germany", id: 4 }
    ],
    cities: [
        { text: "Tirana", id: 1, state: 1 },
      { text: "Vlora", id: 2, state: 1 },
      { text: "Thessaloniki", id: 3, state: 2 },
      { text: "Athens", id: 4, state: 2 },
      { text: "Berlin", id: 5, state: 4 },
      { text: "Hamburg", id: 6, state: 4 },
      { text: "Rome", id: 7, state: 3 },
      { text: "Milano", id: 8, state: 3 }
    ],
    selectedState: null,
    selectedCity: null
  },
  computed: {
    citiesDependOnSelectedState() {
        return this.cities.filter(el => el.state === this.selectedState)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    stateChanged() {
        this.selectedCity = null
    }
  }
})
```